# Insert a jQuery value in a php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've some buttons on a page and I wanna make a div with the content of a WordPress post to be show only when the related button is clicked.

Once I have so many buttons and posts, I was wondering if that is a way to get the value with the name of the button ID that will be clicked with `jQuery` and since the post name related is the same, insert it on `php` to get the content.

I'm not sure if I could do something like this:

```
<div id="btn-group">
<button id="History">History</button>
<button id="Mathematic">Mathematic</button>
<button id="Geography">Geography</button>
<button id="Biology">Biology</button>
</div>

<div id="pages-content">
<?php $page = get_page_by_title( '*something to put the var currentID*' ); echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);?>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
    jQuery(document.body).click(function(evt){
      var clicked = evt.target;
      var currentID = clicked.id;
    })

// show the div only when the button is clicked    
    jQuery(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if ( jQuery(e.target).closest('#btn-group').length ) {
            jQuery('#pages-content').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ajax for Wordpress is your friend, its a bit messy at the beginning, but it works fine and its the only way that I know to share information between PHP and JS

Comment: Use Ajax or as alternative you could hide div with post content and then show it when button is clicked.

Comment: JQuery happens on browser, PHP happens on server. If you need communicate each other you can use Ajax.

Comment: I see! But I'm not sure how to use Ajax... sorry for my bad knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible and in more cooler way :)

OK, lets dig into code.

HTML Side:

```
<div id="btn-group">
    <button id="History" onclick = function() {getData(1)};>History</button>
    <button id="Mathematic" onclick = function() {getData(2)};>Mathematic</button>
    <button id="Geography" onclick=function() {getData(3)};>Geography</button>
    <button id="Biology" onclick = function() {getData(4)};>Biology</button>
</div>

<div id="pages-content">

</div>
```

Now we have added alert function to HTML content, but we need to create this function, I mean we need to write logic how this function works.

```
<script>
    function getData(code)
    { 
        var code = code; //we know that each code describes each subject, that's preliminary known for programmer
        var formData = new FormData(); //we create formData object to send data with it to server
            formData.append("SubjectCode", code); //we have sent code value with name "SubjectCode", it's actually like sending data from php via "Submit" button
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHTTPRequest(); //we create XHR Object
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200)
                { 
                    var responseText = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    var div = document.querySelector("#pages-content");
                     div.innerHTML = responseText;
                }
            } //here we are monitoring request status
            xmlHttp.open("POST", "Server.php"); //same like method="POST" action="server.php", but you write here and not in html form
            xmlHttp.send(formData); //what are we sending to server.
    }    
</script>
```

And server side (PHP):

```
<?php
    $subjectCode = $_POST["SubjectCode"];
    //select * WHERE `subjectCode` = our subject
    //and output that data so that ajax function could receive it..
?>
```

That's all, after that you will have complete asynchronous functionality related to content output.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly didn't work ?

show me screen or something

Comment: I inserted the script on my js file and put this on the php `<?php global $post; ?>
<?php if(is_page('Projetos e Agentes')){ ?>

<div id="btn-group">
    <button id="ANAC" onclick="function() {getData(1)};">ANAC</button>
    <button id="ADEMG" onclick="function() {getData(2)};">ADEMG</button>
</div>

<div id="pages-content">
<?php $my_post = get_page_by_title( $subjectCode = $_POST["SubjectCode"], OBJECT, 'post' );?><?php echo $my_post->post_content;?> </div>
    
<?php } ?>`

Comment: I can help you if you send me teamviewer user/pass and it will be faster for both of us to solve this problem. Also it will be easier to explain some of the key parts

Comment: user: 313 321 389  / pass: z77ya9 ! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: if additional help needed, just add me on skype -> dato-deme :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML :-

```
<div id="btn-group">
    <button class="sub-btn" value="History" id="History">History</button>
    <button class="sub-btn" value="Mathematic" id="Mathematic">Mathematic</button>
    <button class="sub-btn" value="Geography" id="Geography">Geography</button>
    <button class="sub-btn" value="Biology" id="Biology">Biology</button>
</div>
<div id="pages-content">

</div>
```

jQuery :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sub-btn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'server.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {SubjectCode: $this.val()},
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#pages-content").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP :-

```
<?php
$subjectcode = $_POST['SubjectCode'];
```